# Calculate the position of a geographical point on Northwest/Southeast axis

Tags: math, coordinates, geography, gis

longitude can be seen as the position of a geographical point along a West/east axis and latitude along a North/South axis?

How can I calculate the position of a geographical point on a northwest/southeast axis using the data above?

This would be useful for me to study the change of biological trait values along such an axis.

Comment: Given a geographical location I can get its projection onto the N/S axis (I call this its latitude) and its projection onto the E/W axis (I call this its longitude).  Given the same location what number(s) do you want a function to return given both that location and a specification of the hypothesised NW/SE axis ?

Comment: Hi mark, thanks for your reply. I'm not sure that I fully understood it though. What I really need for my analyis is some relative measurement of "south-eastness" of a point, so that I can use this as an independent variable in my analysis.